# Validar URL com ER

Tags: php, validação, url

Tenho uma classe de validação e preciso de um método para validar URL's, mas a função `filter_var` contem falhas para valida-las.

---

<sub>**Um exemplo de 3 URL's:**</sub>

<sub>A URL é completa retorna ***TRUE***

`#1 'http://www.youtube.com' | string(22) "..."`</sub>

<sub>A URL é inválida e mesmo assim a função retorna ***TRUE***

`#2 'tp://www.youtube.com'   | string(20) "..."`</sub>

<sub>A URL retorna ***FALSE***

`#3 'youtube.com'            | bool(false)`</sub>

---

Não sei se a falha é com o protocolo `HTTP|HTTPS`, ainda não esgotei testes.
As regras para validação de URL's pelo que eu vi são enormes e não compreendo muito bem todas as regras.

Pensei em usar `preg_match` antes de `filter_var` para encontrar o protocolo com a ER:
`"/(http|https):\/\/(.*?)$/i"`.

Meu receio é que isso também falhe.
Alguém tem uma sugestão simples para esse impasse - que não seja uma ER complexa?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Que me conste não existe **A** expressão regular para validar URLs e a culpa, em parte, é/são da(s) RFc(s). E é assim para qualquer dado que dependa de uma.

As funções de filtragem do PHP até seguem as especificações devidas, mas elas não cobrem todos os casos e, para outros, a fim de não evitar falsos-positivos, ela diminui a restrição de acordo com a sua necessidade, através das flags de configuração, permitindo a você ter a flexibilidade necessária para cada caso.

Apenas para referências futuras, por padrão, caso omitido o segundo argumento, ela apenas trata o dado como uma string comum.

No seu caso, dada a ausência da forma de uso, eu imagino que esteja fazendo isso:

```
filter_var( 'http://www.youtube.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL );
```

A primeira URL valida pois contém os principais elementos de uma URL que são o *schema*, o domínio e o [TLD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain).

No segundo caso também valida porque também tem os três components básicos, mesmo que um deles seja errado.

Para que a segunda URL também retornasse **FALSE** seria preciso combinar a primeira flag com *FILTER_FLAG_SCHEME_REQUIRED*.

Já a terceira URL é válida para o usuário, para o browser, mas não para para a RFC pois carece de um dos componentes básicos requeridos pela especificação.

O que você poderia é, como em tudo que vêm do usuário, antes mesmo de validar, seria sanitizar a URL. Algumas coisas que me ocorrem:

- Verificar se não existem *schemas* quebrados, como na segunda URL e corrigi-los, seja removendo ou consertando quando e se possível
- Adicionar o *schema* padrão **http://** no início da URL caso ausente (ou qebrado e ora removido), afinal, um URL FTP ou HTTPS (ou ED2K, Magnet, torrent...) que não tenham tais prefixos específicos não serão tratados como especiais de todos jeito.

E sempre avisar o usuário através de uma dica na *GUI* de que o formato é *http://domain.com*. Se ele digitar errado, o sistema não conseguir consertar a verificação falhar, avisado ele foi e vai ter de preencher tudo de novo.

Comment: Boa aula essa, vou fazer uma leitura atenta e depois comento pelo pc. Estou usando a flag citada... Esqueci de coloca-la na questao. valeu

Comment: +1... Eu uso JS para fazer a mascara, mas a validação fica no lado do server e retorna as mensagens de volta... Com tantas possibilidades, sanitizar a entrada da URL, não teria que saber todas as regras para não cometer erro?

Comment: Como programador, sou bastante pessimista. Penso sempre no pior cenário possível e no final desses cenários sempre tem um usuário (>.<). Se prazo e pequenas perdas de performance não forem problema pra você vale a pena sim se debruçar sobre a [RFC 3696 Section 4.2](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3696#section-4.2) (salvo engano) e outras de que ela derive se for o caso e tentar cobrir o máximo possível dos casos e se você (seu programa) não conseguir resolver por ele mesmo, infelizmente, retorne o erro pro usuário, fazer o quê.

Answer (score 4):

O seu segundo exemplo é uma URL **válida**! As [URLs](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL) possuem o formato geral:

```
esquema://máquina/caminho/recurso
```

`http` e `https` são apenas dois exemplos de esquema (*schema*; às vezes chamado de "protocolo"). Outros seriam o `ftp`, o `file`... Nada impede que alguém crie um esquema `tp`, por isso o validador aceitou seu segundo exemplo.

Se você quer restringir o esquema a `http` e `https`, eu sugiro simplesmente testar por isso logo após o `filter_var`:

```
strpos($url, "http:") === 0 || strpos($url, "https:") === 0
```

(Nota: por que eu não testo só se o prefixo é `http`? Porque isso aceitaria URLs como `httpabc://...`)

Comment: Eu nao sabia isso sobre a schema, sei do ftp, mas nao que pudesse ser criado. Vou ler mais sobre o assumto, valeu.

Comment: Acho mais seguro comparar com FALSE e não com zero, só por via das dúvidas.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto Desculpe, não entendi. Na realidade, não tenho muita experiência com PHP, copiei essa implementação de "startsWith" [dessa resposta no SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10473026/520779). Pelo meu entendimento, quando o termo de busca for um prefixo da string essa função vai retornar zero, e não false, ou estou enganado? Segundo [essa documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strpos.php), ela só vai retornar false se a substring **não** for encontrada.

Comment: Então, é que o PHP é cheio de "achismos", se intrometendo com *cast* automatico e tal. Com as funções de string que **podem** retornar FALSE o senso comum é o de se comparar, negativamente, com FALSE (`strpos( $s, 'string' !== FALSE )`) pois se algo influenciar a variável (aqui, **$s**) pode ser que antes de strpos() produza um falso-positivo.

Answer (score 3):

Eu utilizo esta regex e estou satisfeito com os resultados

```
(preg_match("%^(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@|\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}|(?:(?:[a-z\d\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]+-?)*[a-z\d\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\d\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]+-?)*[a-z\d\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]+)*(?:\.[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]{2,6}))(?::\d+)?(?:[^\s]*)?$%iu", $url)))
```

Pode encontrar a regex em https://gist.github.com/dperini/729294

Comment: Na questao eu disse, que nao seja complexa... Se essa é simples entao eu nao sei o que é complicado :) Sou meio leigo com ER

Comment: Caro amigo, tentei ajudar. ER também não é o meu forte, por isso que confio nessa ER que o dperini, mantem e atualiza no github. Quando não consigo resolver, prefiro código testado. Desculpe ocupar seu post. Passar bem.

Comment: Toda explicação sobre a regra está no endereço que coloquei. Assim como comentários e sugestões. A regra não é minha.